# Unique field types and specific GET-parameters for api calls in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: api, headless, apostrophe-cms, fieldtype

I have several questions about Apostrophe CMS:

1. Is it possible to add a unique field type in apostrophe-pieces? I can't find a way to do this.

Edit: I noticed that I wasn't specific enough. I want to make sure that there can't be two instances in the database with the same value in an added field. It should be something like an additional id. Is there an option for this? Maybe something like:

```
addFields: [
    {
        name: 'secondId',
        label: 'Second ID',
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
]
```

2. I want to access the apostrophe-headless api and get a specific element by passing a certain value of one of the created field types of the correspondent piece in a GET-parameter. Is something like this possible?

For example:

Piece:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'article',
    label: 'Article',
    pluralLabel: 'Articles',
    restApi: {
        safeFor: 'manage'
    },
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            label: 'Name',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: 'author',
            label: 'Author',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    ]
};
```

Desired api call for getting all articles which have strored "Jon" as author:

http://example.com/api/v1/article?author=Jon

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Custom field types**

You can add custom field types at project level by extending `apostrophe-schemas` and adding the proper definition. You'll need to add a converter for server-side sanitization and a populator for the front-end of the form field.

You can follow the examples in Apostrophe's schema module, linked are the functions defining a float

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/0bcd5faf84bc7b05c51de7331b17f5929794f524/lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/index.js#L1367
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/0bcd5faf84bc7b05c51de7331b17f5929794f524/lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/public/js/user.js#L991

You would add your definitions in your project level `lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas`'s `index.js` and `public/js/user.js` respectively.

**Filtering**

You can search your piece index for a string like `Jon` by adding `?search=jon` to your query but more likely you want to filter pieces by the value of a join.

If you had piece types `article` and `authors`, you could have a `joinByOne` field in `article`'s schema that lets you relate that article to an `author` piece. Then, by enabling `pieceFilters` you could filter directly on those joined properties.

A complete rundown of `piecesFilters` can be found here https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#filtering-joins-browsing-profiles-by-market

I think you'd also need to mark that filter as safe for api use in your `apostrophe-headless` configuration https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless#filtering-products

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to implement the desired filtering. I read my first question again and I think I didn't make my point clear enough, sorry for that. I edited my question to make things more clearly.

Comment: Can you not utilize the `_id` property of the piece? The fastest path to uniqueness is probably leaning on mongo

Comment: Using the _id property is not really an option for me because in the final product the user should be able to add products with unique productcodes in the backend.

Comment: You could add a new field type as outlined above, `productCodes`, that mimics regular strings and, as part of its `convert` function, fetches all existing product pieces and determines whether or not the current one it is trying to save exists elsewhere. Not sure how performant this will be if you have thousands and thousands of product pieces ..

Comment: Isn't there an easier way? In `apostrophe-users` exists an auto-generated field named email which just accepts unique values. How is it done here?